# Updating attributes in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I am looking for some clarification on permitted params and updating a record.

I understand that whitelisting attributes is now done in the controller, and I create a private method at the bottom of my controller. For example:

```
private
def gallery_params
  params.require(:gallery).permit(:id, :title, :overview, :category_id, gallery_images_attributes: [:id, :gallery_id, :gallery_category_id, :photo, :_destroy])
end
```

if i want to be able to access these attributes within my create action i can pass them through like so

```
@gallery = Gallery.new(gallery_params)
```

I am however a bit stuck on how to permit the same params through my update method

```
def update
@gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
if @gallery.update_attributes(params[:gallery])
  redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Successfully updated Gallery'
else
  render action: 'edit'
end
end
```

I have tried

```
@gallery.update_attributes(params[:gallery].permit(gallery_params))
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply use your `gallery_params` method:

```
if @gallery.update(gallery_params)
```

Comment: thanks, thats worked.. simple aswell, silly of me not to realise

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of separate permission for individual attributes, simply use `gallery_params`